# Maintaining dynamically set View tag on orientation change

Tags: android, android-view, android-orientation

When I set the tag of a `View` with `setTag()` dynamically it is not kept after an orientation change. The answers to a couple of related questions (these two answers in particular - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364325/1386784) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7145210/1386784)) seem to suggest that tags are maintained on orientation changes (memory leaks if a `View` is stored in the tag means that its not released when it should be - i.e. orientation change). Is there any way to keep `View` tags after an orientation change (besides physically implementing your own method)?

I've done up a simple example where the tag is not saved on orientation change. The first `Button` is used to set the tag of the second `Button`. The second `Button` displays its current tag when clicked. On orientation change the tag is **always** null:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        findViewById(R.id.set_tag).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                findViewById(R.id.display_tag).setTag("MY VIEW TAG");
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Tag set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.display_tag).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String s = (String) findViewById(R.id.display_tag).getTag();
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Tag is: "+((s == null) ? "null" : s), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/set_tag"
        android:text="Set Tag"
        android:freezesText="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/display_tag"
        android:text="Display Tag"
        android:freezesText="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Prior to orientation:
[image: Prior to orientation - with tag]

Post orientation:
[image: After orientation - no tag]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a tag is really what you want here. Consider using [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) to preserve any data that needs to persist when the activity gets destroyed and recreated.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString("tag", message);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    message = state.getString("tag");
}
```