# How to keep state for polygons?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

I was reading the documentation for [polygons and polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/polygon-tutorial)
What is not clear to me is how could I keep a state associated with a polygon?
E.g. if I want to do an action on click that depends on whether the polygon was already clicked on or not how could I know that?
Could I use e.g. `tag` to add arbitrary info including if the polygon is in click/state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `setTag()` with custom object which include click state and other data like

```
CustomDefinedObject data = new CustomDefinedObject ();// your defined object
data.isClicked=true
data.otherProperty=false
polyline.setTag(data);
```

and to retrieve info

```
CustomDefinedObject retrievedData = (CustomDefinedObject)polyline.getTag(data);
```

Comment: What happens to the `tag` during the activity lifecycle? Is it kept or not?

Comment: I came across this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518614/maintaining-dynamically-set-view-tag-on-orientation-change) ,to be honest I also  suggest you to try to test it and see result in action